# Netbeans remote existing project doesn't compile

Tags: linux, remote, compile, make, netbeans

I'm trying to create a remote existing project in NetBeans.
For some reasons, the project is built this way on the remote Linux machine:
Project's sources: `/home/bob/workspace/myprojectFolder`
Project's makefile: `/home/bob/workspace/makefile`

I defined a NetBeans project this way:

1. The remote host is defined correctly.
2. NetBeans project location: `/home/bob/workspace/myprojectFolder/NBproj`
3. Make's working directory: `/home/bob/workspace` (actually it's `../..` in the NetBeans: from MBproj, two back)

The in the `makefile` path, there's another file called `common.mk`. `makefile` includes `common.mk` with: `include common.mk` (same path).
When trying to compile with NetBeans I get an error: `makefile:2: common.mk: No such file or directory` and I can't compile remotely.

When doing the same thing with NetBeans installed on the Linux machine. and using local host instead of remote host. with the same project properties, the project get's compiled.

1. Is it possible to see the CWD while compiling with NetBeans?
2. Why does it happen? What's the difference between the remote / local?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Project Services - C/C++ Build Hosts there should be `localhost` and whatever other build hosts are defined.

- double click the remote build host and a window with "**Host Properties**" will popup
- in the **Miscellaneous** section you should see the build host name and the access project files
- And from there you should be able set to "STFP" and then click **OK**

Comment: Please edit and clarify further but is this what you are saying?